# Having trouble getting access to the Object in JSON from url

Tags: javascript, json, object, url, getjson

I am sorry if this sounds stupid, but I have just started learning javascript and json, and I want to get access to the JSON object from the twitter API after doing

```js
var myjson;
$.getJSON('url of the Object', function(data) {
  myjson = json;
});
```

however, after opening myjson, I can't find the object that contains 50 arrays [image of said myjson](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOMlD.png)

I know the object existed when I used $.getJSON [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqYhq.png), so now I am wondering what did I do wrong such that the object has disappeared.

I would really appreciate it if someone could point me in the right directions, as nothing turned up after googling.

also, heres the twitter api that I used,

```html
{"statuses":[{"created_at":"Sun Jul 03 13:03:21 +0000 2016","id":749589344554459137,"id_str":"749589344554459137","text":"RT @Pontifex: Loving and forgiving as God loves and forgives. This is a programme of life that can know no interruptions or exceptions.","truncated":false,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"symbols":[],"user_mentions":[{"screen_name":"Pontifex","name":"Pope
Francis","id":500704345,"id_str":"500704345","indices":[3,12]}],"urls":[]},"metadata":{"iso_language_code":"en","result_type":"recent"},"source":"<a href=\ "http:\/\/twitter.com\/download\/android\" rel=\ "nofollow\">Twitter for Android<\/a>","in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":2656789554,"id_str":"2656789554","name":"Augustine Neto T","screen_name":"NetoTumwebaze","location":"At The Heart Of Africa","description":"Human Resources Officer - MTN Rwanda","url":"http:\/\/t.co\/zzdpXkfiue","entities":{"url":{"urls":[{"url":"http:\/\/t.co\/zzdpXkfiue","expanded_url":"http:\/\/www.mtn.co.rw","display_url":"mtn.co.rw","indices":[0,22]}]},"description":{"urls":[]}},"protected":false,"followers_count":153,"friends_count":148,"listed_count":13,"created_at":"Fri Jul 18 14:03:38 +0000 2014","favourites_count":15,"utc_offset":10800,"time_zone":"Kyiv","geo_enabled":false,"verified":false,"statuses_count":3843,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"is_translation_enabled":false,"profile_background_color":"000000","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/729685855565185024\/KcmSmNA6_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/729685855565185024\/KcmSmNA6_normal.jpg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/2656789554\/1418826532","profile_link_color":"89C9FA","profile_sidebar_border_color":"000000","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"000000","profile_text_color":"000000","profile_use_background_image":false,"has_extended_profile":false,"default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":false,"follow_request_sent":false,"notifications":false},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"retweeted_status":{"created_at":"Sun Jul 03 12:00:08 +0000 2016","id":749573436637261824,"id_str":"749573436637261824","text":"Loving and forgiving as God loves and forgives. This is a programme of life that can know no interruptions or exceptions.","truncated":false,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"symbols":[],"user_mentions":[],"urls":[]},"metadata":{"iso_language_code":"en","result_type":"recent"},"source":"<a href=\"https:\/\/about.twitter.com\/products\/tweetdeck\" rel=\"nofollow\">TweetDeck<\/a>","in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":500704345,"id_str":"500704345","name":"Pope Francis","screen_name":"Pontifex","location":"Vatican City","description":"Welcome to the official Twitter page of His Holiness Pope Francis","url":"http:\/\/t.co\/MlfhXffVrl","entities":{"url":{"urls":[{"url":"http:\/\/t.co\/MlfhXffVrl","expanded_url":"http:\/\/www.news.va","display_url":"news.va","indices":[0,22]}]},"description":{"urls":[]}},"protected":false,"followers_count":9506393,"friends_count":8,"listed_count":24637,"created_at":"Thu Feb 23 11:38:07 +0000 2012","favourites_count":0,"utc_offset":7200,"time_zone":"Rome","geo_enabled":false,"verified":true,"statuses_count":879,"lang":"it","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"is_translation_enabled":true,"profile_background_color":"FFFFFF","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/857999332\/52f4b5a0278e5a44ed595ef3a031a709.jpeg","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/857999332\/52f4b5a0278e5a44ed595ef3a031a709.jpeg","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/507818066814590976\/KNG-IkT9_normal.jpeg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/507818066814590976\/KNG-IkT9_normal.jpeg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/500704345\/1409908226","profile_link_color":"0084B4","profile_sidebar_border_color":"FFFFFF","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"has_extended_profile":false,"default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":false,"follow_request_sent":false,"notifications":false},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"is_quote_status":false,"retweet_count":2679,"favorite_count":5015,"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"lang":"en"},"is_quote_status":false,"retweet_count":2679,"favorite_count":0,"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"lang":"en"}],"search_metadata":{"completed_in":0.032,"max_id":749589344554459137,"max_id_str":"749589344554459137","query":"life","refresh_url":"?since_id=749589344554459137&q=life&include_entities=1","count":2,"since_id":0,"since_id_str":"0"}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code sample json is not existing

Be aware that what happen in your success function:

```
function(data) {
  myjson = data;
}
```

is called asynchronously (when you receive the success response from the api) so if you have checked the content of myjson outside this function it can be that myjson has not be modified yet.

whatever you want to do with this json you need to do it in this function (or call an other function from this one):

```
function(data) {
  myjson = data;
  //do some stuff with myjson
}
```

Comment: I do know that $.getJSON is asynchronous, that's why we can't do var x = $.getJson... however, if this is the case that myjson has not been modified yet, how can I then get access to the object from the url?

Comment: How and where do you verify myjson content ?

Whatever you want to do with this json you need to do it in this function (or call an other function from this one)

Comment: By the way json is not existing in your code sample

Comment: i checked by using console.log(myjson). When you say that i need to do it in this function, do you mean that I need do 
$.getJSON(jsonUrl, function(data) {
        jsonRaw = json;
        var filterTweet = filterTweets(jsonRaw);
});
in order to get access to the object?

Comment: isn't javascript object JSON? in the code sample i showed, the Status:[] is an array of 5 objects with elements in it

Comment: The only available var in your success function is data (and myjson), you should do something with it.
try to console.log(data).
And by the way you should use breakpoints its much easier to understand what happen in a code

Comment: oh my god, i am so stupid, all along I have been trying to find the object in myjson, when it has been sitting in data the whole time. Thank you so much for the help, I cant believe that I lost sleep over this lol.